# How to get string between coordinates in another string, with start and stop coordinates speicifed by a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, sequence

I am trying to get sequences from a genome specified by coordinates in a datframe.

I need to take the start coordinate and the stop coordinate, use the cooridnates to get the sequence within the string and append that sequence to a list.

Here is what my df and string look like

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd   
# initialize list of lists 
data = [['x', 3, 13], ['y', 5, 15], ['z', 7, 17]]   
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Start', 'Stop'])   
# print dataframe. 
df 
sequence = "ATGTCGCCGCTGCTGCTGTGTCGTAGTCAGC"
```

I want to loop through the start and stop coordinates in the dataframe and use the coordinates to sepcify the section of the sequence, and append the seciton to a new list

I have done this:

```
subseq = []

a = sequence[df.iloc[1,1]:df.iloc[1,2]]

subseq.append(a)
```

How would I do this to loop throught the dataframe automatically (idealsl however I would refer to the column by column name)

I am using python

Comment: kindly share ur expected output

Comment: what's you're expected output from the example? without that, this question isn't very clear

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a dataframe.

I would loop through your raw data:

```py
data = [['x', 3, 13], ['y', 5, 15], ['z', 7, 17]]   
sequence = "ATGTCGCCGCTGCTGCTGTGTCGTAGTCAGC"

output = []
for d in data:
    output.append(sequence[d[1]:d[2]])
```

for more succinctly:

```py
data = [['x', 3, 13], ['y', 5, 15], ['z', 7, 17]]   
sequence = "ATGTCGCCGCTGCTGCTGTGTCGTAGTCAGC"

output = [sequence[d[1]:d[2]] for d in data]
```

Both of those output:

```
['TCGCCGCTGC', 'GCCGCTGCTG', 'CGCTGCTGCT']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[sequence[a:b] for a,b in zip(df['Start'], df['Stop'])]
```

Output:

```
['TCGCCGCTGC', 'GCCGCTGCTG', 'CGCTGCTGCT']
```

You can also add that to your dataframe:

```
df['sub'] = [sequence[a:b] for a,b in zip(df['Start'], df['Stop'])]
```

Output:

```
  Name  Start  Stop         sub
0    x      3    13  TCGCCGCTGC
1    y      5    15  GCCGCTGCTG
2    z      7    17  CGCTGCTGCT
```